# Commit to all branches

Tags: git, gitkraken

I have got *master* branch and some other branches in GitKraken. I have a java class file, which stores data server address. I want to commit changes of this file to all of my branches. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to commit the change to one branch, then `cherry-pick` that commit onto the other branches.

As far as i'm aware, there isn't a native command to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single git command that would do this.  You could write a script to automate the repetitive steps...

I would consider finding a common merge base to all the branches into which you want to merge this change, creating a new branch from there, making the change on that branch, and then merging it into each of the target branches.

Compared to cherry-picking (which steadweb presents as the only option, but which certainly is *not* the only option), this should give better conflict resolution down the road.

Comment: Making new branch and merging into other branches looks to be good idea. Thanks for your help.